# ¿Cómo se coloca en SQL server un cero para números menores a 10?

Tags: sql, sql-server

En caso de que el número aleatorio sea menor de `10`.

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (20 - 1) + 1)
```

¿Cómo hago para que el resultado de un **cero** adelante?

En el número del ejemplo quiero como resultado `09` pero si es mayor a `10` no quiero que salga `010`.

¿Eso se puede hacer? En el caso de que si, necesito que me expliquen como, por favor y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que requieres, puedes usar la función `PATH`:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*(20-1)+1) AS VARCHAR), 2)
```

[Aquí](http://rextester.com/LSBH44814) puedes un ejemplo y sus resultados.